# Gradient of $f(x) = 1^T \left[ \left( x - 1 \left[1^T x\right] \right) \odot \left(x - 1 \left[1^T x\right] \right) \right]$ w.r.t. $x$

Tags: matrix-calculus

How to compute the gradient of
$$\eqalign{
f(x) &= 1^T \left[ \left( x -  1 \left[1^T x\right] \right) \odot \left(x -   1  \left[1^T x\right]  \right) \right]\cr
}$$ where $x \in M_{n,1}(\mathbb{R})$, $1 \in M_{n,1}$ is a column vector with all ones, $\odot$ is an element-wise multiplication.

Comment: The quantity $(x-1^Tx)$ is dimensionally incompatible. If $x$ is a vector and $1$ is a vector, then $1^Tx$ is a scalar. You can't subtract a scalar from a vector.

Comment: I have done some modification. How about now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the matrix of ones $11^T = J$, we can write $f$ in terms of a variable $a$ with differential:

\begin{align}
    a&= (I-J)x \\
    da &= (I - J)dx
\end{align}

where $I$ is the identity matrix.

Replacing $a$ and writing the expression in terms of the Frobenius product we can calculate the differential of $f$:

\begin{align}
    f &= 1 : a \odot a\\
    df &= 1: 2a \odot da\\
    &= 1 \odot 2a : da\\
    &= 2a : da \\
    &= 2(I-J)x : (I - J)dx\\
    &= 2(I-J)^2x : dx
\end{align}

Thus:

\begin{equation}
    \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 2(I-J)^2x = 2x +2(n-2)Jx 
\end{equation}

edit: thanks @greg

Comment: Since $J^2=nJ\,$ you can simplify the term $$(I-J)^2 = I+(n-2)J$$

Comment: Nice, thank you