# Gradient of $f = \gamma \ \left( x - 1\mu(x) \right) \ \left( \sigma(x) + \epsilon \right)^{-1/2} + 1\beta$ w.r.t. $x$, $\gamma$, and $\beta$

Tags: matrix-calculus

How to compute the gradient of 
$$\eqalign{
f &= \gamma \ \left( x - 1\mu(x) \right) \ \left( \sigma(x) + \epsilon \right)^{-1/2} + 1\beta \cr
\mu(x) &= \alpha \ 1^Tx \cr
\sigma(x) &= \alpha \sum_{k=1}^m \left( x_k - \mu(x) \right)^2 \equiv \alpha 1^T \left[ \left( x -  1 \left[\alpha 1^T x\right] \right) \odot \left(x -   1  \left[\alpha 1^T x\right]  \right) \right]\cr
}$$ where $1^T$ is a row vector with all ones, $\odot$ is an element-wise multiplication, and $\alpha$ and $\epsilon$ are known scalars.

---

My partial attempt:

I am not sure whether I am following the matrix calculus method, but I share my attempt. So, my intention is to compute the differential firstly and then the gradient.

Following [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3178807/gradient-of-fx-1t-left-left-x-1-left1t-x-right-right-odot-le), the matrix of scaled ones can be defined as
\begin{align}
J := \alpha 1 1^T \ .
\end{align}

Defining another matrix $M := I - J$, where $I$ is an identity matrix.

Also, defining by [following](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3178807/gradient-of-fx-1t-left-left-x-1-left1t-x-right-right-odot-le) such that
\begin{align}
\sigma(x) := \alpha 1^T \left(M x \odot M x \right) \Longrightarrow d\sigma(x) = 2 \alpha M^2x : dx,
\end{align}
where double dot $:$ notation is for the inner product.

So, the function can be rewritten as
\begin{align}
f = \gamma \ M x \ \left( \sigma(x) + \epsilon \right)^{-1/2} + 1\beta 
\end{align}

Differential is

\begin{align}
df 
&= d\gamma \ M x \ \left( \sigma(x) + \epsilon \right)^{-1/2}  \\
& \quad + \gamma M dx \ \left( \sigma(x) + \epsilon \right)^{-1/2}  \\
& \quad + \gamma \ M x \ \frac{-1}{2} \left( \sigma(x) + \epsilon \right)^{-3/2} \ d\sigma(x)  \\
& \quad + 1d\beta \ ,
\end{align}

is it correct? if not please help me to correct it.

1. To compute $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \gamma}$, we set $dx, d\sigma(x),  d\beta  = 0$ such that
   \begin{align}
   \frac{\partial f}{\partial \gamma} =  M x \ \left( \sigma(x) + \epsilon \right)^{-1/2} \ .
   \end{align}
2. And, 
   \begin{align}
   \frac{\partial f}{\partial \beta} =  1 \ .
   \end{align}
3. To compute  $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$, we set $d\gamma, d\beta = 0$
   \begin{align}
   &df 
   = \gamma M dx \ \left( \sigma(x) + \epsilon \right)^{-1/2}   - \frac{1}{2} \gamma \ M x \  \left( \sigma(x) + \epsilon \right)^{-3/2} \ \left( 2 \alpha M^2x : dx \right)  \\
   \Longrightarrow   \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= \gamma M \ \left( \sigma(x) + \epsilon \right)^{-1/2} - \gamma \ M x \  \left( \sigma(x) + \epsilon \right)^{-3/2}  \alpha \left( M^2x  \right)^T
   \end{align}

Are the above gradients correct?